# Textures getting pixelated when painting with zoom out

Tags: texturing

My text is full hd, its tga blablabla.

When i paint using stencil, with zoom out, the texture gets pixelated. However if i paint them when i'm zoomed in, they don't.

Why is that ?[image]

Btw, i REALLY need to be able to paint this with zoom out, without this pixelated problem.